# How get data between two ranges dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL I write a SELECT statement to fetch data between two range dates, using between and ..if i use betwenn ('01/01/2013') and ('31/12/2015') i get all data but i want just between the specified dates...**exclude year of 2014**

Ex:

```
select * 
from xxx 
 where  date between ('01/01/2013') and ('31/12/2013')
                        and  date between ('01/01/2015') and ('31/12/2015')
```

But it returned 0 rows.

Comment: Use `Or` instead of `And`

Comment: thanks man ...it works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Use `or` instead of `and`

```
select * 
from your_table
where date between ('01/01/2013') and ('31/12/2013')
   or date between ('01/01/2015') and ('31/12/2015')
```

You don't want data that is in both date ranges what is not possible at the same time. You want data that is in either one of them.

Answer (score 1):

A succinct way that may not perform as well is:

```
select * 
from xxx 
where Year(date) in (2013, 2015)
```